# Handle error of a specific time raised at any point

Tags: django, django-1.8

Occasionally we are getting `OperationalError: FATAL` and we have no idea why. I want to handle this error wherever it happens in the application and send me a personal email. I would also like to set up a system command call to inspect the database activity (I know this is a bad idea but it's the only thing I can think of to try to figure out why this is happening).

How can I do this? Summarized: catch an error of a specific type raised at any point and handle it in a custom and granular way.

Comment: Django already has basic [email reporting on errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/error-reporting/#server-errors). Is that not enough? Doesn't it report on `OperationalError` as well?

Comment: Also, the full error stacktrace should give you some hints as to where the errors orinigated.

Comment: @Ralf of course it reports it, I just want to handle it separately and in a granular way (e.g. get a personal email instead of logging it in the regular error channels or do whatever I want with the exception object, the traceback, etc... again, granularity). And no, the full stacktrace gives 0 hint. Once max connections is reached (and this is the true problem) any connection whatsoever will raise that error, so the report of such errors is useless to tackle the root cause.

Comment: @Ralf also let me remind you I am not asking how to fix my error (I would create a separate question for that). I am asking how to handle any `OperationalError` (or whatever type I want to handle in a special way) raised in the application in a custom and granular way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an middleware to handle your exception. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception

For example

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django.db import OperationalError
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class RedirectToRefererResponse(HttpResponseRedirect):
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        redirect_to = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/')
        super(RedirectToRefererResponse, self).__init__(
            redirect_to, *args, **kwargs)

class HandleOperationalErrorMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if isinstance(exception, OperationalError):

            send_mail(
                'Subject here',
                'Here is the message.',
                'from@example.com',
                ['to@example.com'],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
            return RedirectToRefererResponse(request)
```

Comment: Heads up: maybe you and the OP already now this, but there are differences between [current middleware styles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware) and those used in [`Django 1.8`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/) (the question is tagged with `1.8`). Just to keep in mind while testing this solution.